# Jquery TOOLS library - Tool tips

Tags: jquery, tooltip, javascript

I'm trying to get these tooltips to work. But even though I tried to download their standalone example ( http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/index.htm ) I can't get these to work.

Can someone explain why this is? I don't see the jQuery library included anywhere in the code.. Can someone help me?

How can the example work online, then when i downloaded the entire page, with all sub files, it doesn not. I just want these awesome tooltips !

Answer (score 0):

Actually at http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/index.htm, a js script containing all the Jquery Tools scripts plus Jquery is included.
But the reason that the saved page doesn't work:
When you go to [that page](http://jquerytools.org/demos/tooltip/index.htm), the `.tooltip()` runs on all `<img>` tags, and removes their `title` attribute consequently, so when you save this page, there is no `title` attribute for that `<img>` tags. and therefore `.tooltip()` find nothing to make tooltip from, when is called on saved page.